# using pikepdf in python

Tags: python, pdf, metadata, pikepdf

After installing pikepdf, while trying code with pikepdf, I am getting error messages as below :

[image]

Comment: Please visit [How to Ask](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It is recommended to paste code and error messages as text over embedding an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's `Pdf`, not `pdf`. Use:

```py
from pikepdf import Pdf
```

2. Using `from pikepdf import ...` does not actually import `pikepdf` itself. Run this to load it:

```py
import pikepdf
```

3. It's `Pdf.open()` not `pikepdf.open()`

It seems best for you to review the [docs](https://pikepdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for `pikepdf`.

Answer (score 0):

You can restart your kernel of your notebook and install pikepdf

`!pip install pikepdf`

Then you should import it by

`from pikepdf import pdf`

and so on.

You should install your dependencies first then run the code.